# Multidimensional tensor to nn.Linear module

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I have a problem where a input tensor of size = [B,C,F] is given to a Fully connected Layer (nn.Linear).

Now from what I understood (link https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multi-dimensional-inputs-in-pytorch-linear-method-in-python/) the Linear module works in this way: for each C it applies the ***same*** linear transform A.

Is there a way to have a **different** A_i for each channel C without needing to implement manually each of them?

I thought of creating a sort of wrapper module in which I iterate over the dimension C in a for loop but I know for loops are not recommended for computational time issues.